# Parsing string into parameters and then concatenate some of them

Tags: c

I have task to make family binary  tree. In this task I need to implement some commands (e.g. add,draw,list..) First of all I need to tokenize standard input .For example "add Walburga [f] mother Sirius Black [m]") to find which commands , names,surnames, relationships and genders are entered.
I have done this with strtok function, and now I have array, which contains every separated string from standard input as parameters. But now I need to concatenate name and surname (if exists) as one parameter.

Comment: The indentation on this code is cancerous. Could you clean it up a bit?

Comment: Are you required to get the full string from the user all at once instead of asking first for command, then for name, then for gender etc?

Comment: full string from the user all at once.Therefore  add <person 1> <gender> <relation> <person 2><gender>

Answer (score 1):

If the input will always have the format:

```
command fullname1 [gender] relation fullname2 [gender]
```

I suggest an approach with `strchr()` to find the first space and call it  `command_end`. Then find the first `[` and call `position of [ - 1` = `fullname1_end` etc.

Then you find the length of the token with `command_end - command_start`for example and `strncpy()` the length to an array and so on.

So you would get something like this (I've used very verbose names to avoid comments):

```
int main(void)
{   
    char input[] = "add Walburga Granger [f] mother Sirius Black [m]";
    char command[30];
    char fullname1[30];
    char gender1[4];
    char rel[30];
    char fullname2[30];
    char gender2[4];

    char* command_start = input;
    char* command_end = strchr(input, ' ');   // find the first whitespace of input
    char* fullname1_start = command_end + 1;  
    char* gender1_start = strchr(input, '[');  // find the first '[' of input
    char* fullname1_end = gender1_start - 1;
    char* gender1_end = strchr(gender1_start, ' ');  // find the first space after gender1 and so on...
    char* rel_start = gender1_end + 1;
    char* rel_end = strchr(rel_start, ' ');
    char* fullname2_start = rel_end + 1;
    char* gender2_start = strchr(fullname2_start, '[');
    char* gender2_end = strchr(gender2_start, '\0');
    char* fullname2_end = gender2_start - 1;

    int command_length = command_end - command_start;
    strncpy(command, command_start, command_length);
    command[command_length] = '\0';

    int fullname1_length = fullname1_end - fullname1_start;
    strncpy(fullname1, fullname1_start, fullname1_length);
    fullname1[fullname1_length] = '\0';

    printf("command: %s\n", command);
    printf("fullname1: %s\n", fullname1);
}
```

Output:

```
command: add
fullname1: Walburga Granger
```

Another approach would be to iterate over the input trying to find those keys characters along the way, like:

```
int main(void)
{   
    char input[] = "add Walburga Granger [f] mother Sirius Black [m]";
    char command[30];
    char name1[30];
    char gender1[4];
    char rel[30];
    char name2[30];
    char gender2[4];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    // extract command
    for (j = 0; i < strlen(input); i++, j++)
    {
        if (input[i] == ' ')
            break;
        command[j] = input[i];
    }
    command[j] = '\0';
    i++;

    // extract first fullname1
    for (j = 0; i < strlen(input); i++, j++)
    {
        if (input[i] == '[')
            break;
        name1[j] = input[i];
    }
    name1[j - 1] = '\0';

    // extract gender1
    for (j = 0; i < strlen(input); i++, j++)
    {
        if (input[i] == ' ')
            break;
        gender1[j] = input[i];
    }
    gender1[j] = '\0';

and so on....
```

Third approach to salvage the majority of your code. You would insert this snippet after you get your command tokens.

```
char fullname1[100];
char fullname2[100];

// build fullname1 
strcpy(fullname1, commands[1]);
i = 2;
while (commands[i][0] != '[')
{
    strcat(fullname1, " ");
    strcat(fullname1, commands[i]);
    i++;
}

// build fullname2
i += 2;
strcpy(fullname2, commands[i]);
i++;
while (commands[i][0] != '[')
{
    strcat(fullname2, " ");
    strcat(fullname2, commands[i]);
    i++;
}

printf("%s\n", fullname1);
printf("%s\n", fullname2);
```

Comment: @АлександарСтојичић I have added a third approach to salvage the majority of your code. It iterates over your tokens analyzing the first char to break the loop. It concatenates the commands along the way.

Comment: third version will help me a lot, thank you very much once more.

Answer (score 0):

I think `sprintf` is what you want.

```
char fullname[strlen(commands[4]) + strlen(commands[5]) + 2]; // plus 2 for ' '  and '\0' 
sprintf(fullname, "%s %s", commands[4], commands[5]);
/* fullname = "Sirius Black" */
```

Comment: But then it wouldn't work for `add Walburga [f] mother Sirius Potter Black [m]` or `add Walburga Granger [f] mother Sirius [m]`

Comment: Exactly so, I need a universal solution, if it is possible.